# I want to implement SeekBar in android ,But when i run the below program my emulator shows error that "Unfortunately SeekBar has been stopped"

Tags: android, android-studio, seekbar

When I change the seekbar in spite of showing the value it says "unfortunately SeekBarActivity has been stopped"

activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sb"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="99dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="201dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="326dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sb"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:text=""
    tools:ignore="UnknownId"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="99dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="219dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mypc.seekbarapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
SeekBar sb;
RatingBar rb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    sb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.sb);
    rb=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rb);
    sb.setMax(100);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
       int pro=0;
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            pro=progress;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          tv.setText(pro);
            //  
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pro,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
    rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, 
boolean fromUser) {
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
   String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
   .show();
        }
    });



}
}
```

my Stack trace:

```
      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
    .run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
09-04 17:37:04.097 2773-2773/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2773 SIG: 
9
```

Where I am wrong?? Any help will b appreciated, thanks in advance.
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

Comment: You cut off  half the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `tv.setText(pro);` when pro is an int value int argument in setText is an string id such as `R.string.some_id` when you call it with an int and Android can not find string resource with an id equals to pro value you get Resource not found exception. you should change it to:

```
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        int pro=0;
        String proStr = "";
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            pro=progress;
            proStr = String.valueOf(pro);// convert int to String
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
          tv.setText(proStr); // use String instead of int
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, proStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // use String instead of int
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the mediastream isn't keeping up with the position of the seeker.

When you update the seeker, make sure the content you're trying to seek to is already in queue.